# WPF Dispatcher issue

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, asynchronous

I'm attempting to update my app to use WPF instead of WinForms and have a problem I need a few pointers as I can't figure out what is wrong....

The code below is from my Winform app which works fine

```
private delegate void LoginAsyncCallbackDelegate(IAsyncResult result);
private void LoginAsyncCallback(IAsyncResult result)
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        try
        {
            LoginAsyncCallbackDelegate d = new LoginAsyncCallbackDelegate(LoginAsyncCallback);
            this.Invoke(d, new object[] { result });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            AddErrorToList(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        DRVis.upx.api.global.LoginResp resp = APIWrapper.UPGlobalService.Endlogin(result);

        var state = (CustomAsyncStateContainer)result.AsyncState;

        // Session manager
        if (resp != null && resp.header != null && resp.header.sessionToken != null)
            SessionTokenManager.ReturnSessionToken(resp.header.sessionToken);

        DisplayLogin(resp, state);
    }
}
```

The following are changes I've made in an attempt to make it work in WPF but the app crashes on the line **if (!this.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())**

```
private delegate void LoginAsyncCallbackDelegate(IAsyncResult result);
private void LoginAsyncCallback(IAsyncResult result)
{
    if (!this.Dispatcher.CheckAccess()) //Progam Crashes here!!
    {
        try
        {
            LoginAsyncCallbackDelegate d = new LoginAsyncCallbackDelegate(LoginAsyncCallback);
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, d, new object[] { result });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            AddErrorToList(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        DRVis.upx.api.global.LoginResp resp = APIWrapper.UPGlobalService.Endlogin(result);

        var state = (CustomAsyncStateContainer)result.AsyncState;

        // Session manager
        if (resp != null && resp.header != null && resp.header.sessionToken != null)
            SessionTokenManager.ReturnSessionToken(resp.header.sessionToken);

        DisplayLogin(resp, state);
    }
}
```

with stack trace....

```
The error time: 16/08/2012 13:06
Exception: System.ArgumentException: Object of type 'System.Object[]' cannot be converted to type 

'System.IAsyncResult'.
   at System.RuntimeType.TryChangeType(Object value, Binder binder, CultureInfo culture, Boolean needsSpecialCast)
   at System.RuntimeType.CheckValue(Object value, Binder binder, CultureInfo culture, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.CheckArguments(Object[] parameters, Binder binder, BindingFlags invokeAttr, 

CultureInfo culture, Signature sig)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InvokeArgumentsCheck(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, 

Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 

numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
```

Can someone help me get the correct syntax to replace this.InvokeRequired and this.Invoke in WPF or point out something obvious I'm missing?

Thanks
O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, d, new object[] { result });
```

should be :

```
this.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, d, result);
```

?